# Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, beanshell

When I replace selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0 by the selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0 in %Jmeter%lib folder then I'm getting this error:

Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import java.io.FileReader; import java.io.FileWriter; impor . . . ''

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsESRv.CSVWriter;

Boolean result=true;
public WebDriver driver;
try
{
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Projects\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver=new ChromeDriver();

     driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://something.com/registration/");
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20000);

     String uname= bsh.args[0];
     String pass= bsh.args[1];

      // Logged In 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'menu-item')]//*[text()='Log In']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(new String[] {uname});
     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(new String[] {pass});
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='woocommerce-login-nonce']/following-sibling::*[@name='login']")).click();

     // Logged Out
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='masthead']//*[text()='Sign out']")).click();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
    IsSuccess = false;
    ResponseCode = "500";
    ResponseMessage = ex.getMessage();
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
} 
catch (Throwable thex) 
{
    System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
finally 
{
    driver.quit();
}
IsSuccess=result;
return result;
```

Code is written in Beanshell Sampler in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replacing just only one Selenium library is not enough, you need to upgrade other dependencies as well

   - Install clean JMeter
   - Download http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.1/selenium-java-3.1.0.zip file and unpack **all the .jars** somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (JMeter's "lib" folder is fine)
   - Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up
2. In order to see the "normal" stacktrace amend your catch block to look like:

   ```
   catch (Exception ex) {
       log.error("Something went wrong", ex);
   }
   ```
3. Consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as Groovy is more Java-compliant and has much better performance. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Replacing single Selenium-Server-Standalone jar is enough, you just need to install clean or new Jmeter.
Thanks for helping me.....